# Jquery Ajax and json

Tags: php, jquery

I am sending a value to mysql query throught ajax. I get output from query as array. I used `echo json_encode($var);`

If my array size is more than 1, my success function is not getting called. I could see the response and status code 200 in fire bug.

How should I retrieve the value in my success function ?

```
  success: function(data){
         ob = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
  }
```

**Update**
my Json response from firebug

```
{"uid":"4",
"name":"ram\u00fcrmeg\u00f6zl\u00fcer",
"pic_big":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-prn1\/4149__3333_n.jpg"}
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "x.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: y,
        success: function(data){    
         }
})
```

Comment: Can you explain `If my array size is more than 1, my success function is not getting called`. with proper data

Comment: Show us the output for the echo in both cases.

Comment: @Yougesh Suthar: I could see the response from firebug in form of array so I mean this array.

Comment: @Sanchit:I am already echoing it. Can you tell me, how to retrieve that in success fn.

Comment: I think you need to show us the entire ajax call you are making. Your javascript success function looks file.

Comment: try `console.log(data);`. what is the output?

Comment: @Sanchit:I have updated json to my question.

Comment: @Jai:If my array size is more than one then console is also not working, tried it before only.

Comment: Show us more javascript. Your json is good and your success function looks good.

Comment: @Sanchit:Updated my jquery.

Comment: @Sanchit:Actually the response is coming from facebook.

Comment: @Sanchit: How about showing a sample snippet to me.

Comment: You don't need to parse data once you get it with `dataType:'json'` The `$.parseJSON(data)` has already been done for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below and see if you get any alert.

```
if(!$.isEmptyObject(data))
       { 
       alert (data);  
       var len = data.length;
       for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
    var var1 = [data[i].uid];
    var var2 = [data[i].name];
            var var3 = [data[i].pic_big];   

      }
else{alert('No data')}
```

Comment: @ram even the alerts? I am assuming you have placed the if statement in the function(data){} part.

Comment: @alert(data) is working. I did not under stand this.'I am assuming you have placed the if statement in the function(data){} part.'

Comment: :I should decode the data variable first in success fn right.Can you pls show me a sample full success fn.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
        url: "x.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: y,
        success: function(data){

           $.each(data, function() {
              var uid = this.uid; // etc
           } 

          // this works alone if your response is wrapped in [ ], if not:
          if(!data.length) {
              var uid = data.uid;
          } else { // above $.each code 
          }

      }
```

jsFiddle of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y73xe/

Comment: :If my json is this {"uid":"4",
"name":"ram\u00fcrmeg\u00f6zl\u00fcer",
"pic_big":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-prn1\/4149__3333_n.jpg"}
{"uid":"5",
"name":"ram\u00fcrmeg\u00f6zl\u00fcer",
"pic_big":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-prn1\/4149__3333_n.jpg"}{"uid":"6",
"name":"ram\u00fcrmeg\u00f6zl\u00fcer",
"pic_big":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-prn1\/4149__3333_n.jpg"}
Nothing gets alerted.If it is {"uid":"4",
"name":"ram\u00fcrmeg\u00f6zl\u00fcer",
"pic_big":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-prn1\/4149__3333_n.jpg"}, i get alerted.

Comment: That's because it's not a valid JSON array, you need [ ] around that JSON string to make it a proper array, and then the $.each will work.

Comment: How to add [] this. I get an array from facebook api and passing it to json_encode();

Comment: I think the problem is the parsing, the json_encode or the $.parseJSON. You need to simply use the response coming back from Facebook, which should be in a valid JSON array format (with the []).

Comment: :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570173/facebook-user-table-fql-to-json-encode Can you answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Your response is already an Object, no need to parseJSON it. Just do this for getting the values:

```
console.log(data.uid);
console.log(data.name);
console.log(data.pic_big);
```

Or whatever you wanna do with those values.