# Facebook user table fql to json_encode

Tags: php, facebook

I am using user table from fql.I am passing array to json_encode(). Facebook json format is not corrct, it is excluding []. How do I add this in my code.

Below code is a example but I do not under stand that code.

user table https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user

I want name,uid.

```
//to get album cover
    $fql2    =   "select  src from photo where pid = '" . $values['cover_pid'] . "'";
    $param2  =   array(
     'method'    => 'fql.query',
     'query'     => $fql2,
     'callback'  => ''
    );

    $fqlResult2   =   $facebook->api($param2);
    $jsarr  =   array();
    foreach( $fqlResult2 as $keys2 => $values2){
    }
    if ($values['name'] != 'Profile Pictures'){
        $jsarr['src'] = $album['src'];

            $count += 1;

    if ($count == 1){
    $outputStr .= "[";}
    else {
    $outputStr .= ",";}
    $outputStr .= json_encode($values2);
    }
}
$outputStr .= "]";
$outputStr = str_replace("{","[",$outputStr);
$outputStr = str_replace("}","]",$outputStr);
echo $outputStr;
}
?>
```

Comment: at first fb is using PHP too, so should be strange if they did something incorrect in encoding json?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the Facebook PHP SDK, it automatically decodes the returned json object into a PHP array. If you need a json object from it, you'll have to use `json_encode` on it after you finish processing it.

You've got some **major** problems with your php code. Just to get started:

- Your `foreach` loop ends as soon as it starts with the `}` on the next line.
- Where do you define the variables `$values` and `$album`?
- You are referencing `$values2` outside of your `foreach` loop.
- You are appending to an uninitialized variable on your line `$outputStr .= "[";`.
- If you pass `json_encode()` a proper php array of data, it will make a complete json object. You shouldn't need to be appending brackets of any kind.

Comment: :I am using FQL so the output will be array,I am passing this array to json_encode but json is not coming in correct format. How doI format it. This is my response {"uid":"4",
"name":"ram\u00fcrmeg\u00f6zl\u00fcer",
"pic_big":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-prn1\/4149__3333_n.jpg"}
{"uid":"5",
"name":"ram\u00fcrmeg\u00f6zl\u00fcer",
"pic_big":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-prn1\/4149__3333_n.jpg"}{"uid":"6",
"name":"ram\u00fcrmeg\u00f6zl\u00fcer",
"pic_big":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-prn1\/4149__3333_n.jpg"}
I think, [] is missing.